# How can I use react native datetime picker

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, datetimepicker

As I want to use datepicker I'm getting this error

```
 null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.RNDateTimePickerManager.getDefaultDisplayValue')
```

**Source codes**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';

const ExpenseStepThree = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());

  const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
    setDate(currentDate);
  };

  return <DateTimePicker value={date} onChange={onChange} />;
};
export default ExpenseStepThree;
```

**Measure to fix issue I did**

- pod-install
- npm install @react-native-community/datetimepicker --save
  **Device specification**
- Xcode 12.5
- "react": "17.0.2",
- "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.5.2",
- "react-native": "0.66.1",

Comment: are you using vanilla react-native or expo cli?

Comment: I'm using Vanilla react-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [react-native-modal-datetime-picker](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker) package instead.